# overloading PHP functions to perform an action first

Tags: php, codeigniter, overloading

I was wondering how I could overload a standard function in php. Specifically, I'm trying to implement security checks on certain functions. As such, I would like to redefine write as:

```
function fwrite($handle, $string, $length = null) {
  if (doMyChecks()) {
    original_fWrite($handle, $string, $length);
  } else {
    recordViolation();
  }
}
```

I'm using CodeIgniter, so I would put this code in `index.php` to make it applicable for all pages called through the framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you could use the PHP function `override_function()`.  From the [PHP.net site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php):

```
override_function('test', '$a,$b', 'echo "DOING TEST"; return $a * $b;');
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was looking for. At the bottom of the page it also shows how to call the original function, so it looks like I'm good to go :)

Comment: does this work in standard PHP? For some reason I'm getting "Call to undefined function override_function()"